# How to write Robotframework log and any keyword output in one line?

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

I want to print the output of any built-in or custom keyword using `Log` command in one line.
for eg.

```
Log    Evaluate    1 + 2
```

This shows error that value of INFO for `Log` function is incorrect, i mean it assumes that Evaluate is parameter of Log function. I am aware that i can assign the value of `Evaluate` to a variable and then log that variable. But this adds multiple entries in log file. so just wondering if one liner is possible to do just as we do in python

```
def Evaluate(a, b):
   return a+b

print(Evaluate(1,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a library with a keyword that will log the return value of `Evaluate`, but it will be the same as storing the return value of `Evaluate` in the Robot Framework script. So a one liner is possible `${retval}=    Evaluate    1 + 2` but in general keywords are not substituted by their return value when passed as a parameter.

```python
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def evaluate_and_log_return_value(expression):
    retval= BuiltIn().evaluate(expression)
    BuiltIn().log(retval)
```

The test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     var.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Evaluate And Log Return Value    1 + 2
    
Test 2
    ${retval}=    Evaluate    1 + 2
```

You can check the output to see that basically the two are the same because variable assignments are logged by default. You do not have to call `Log` again if you are interested in the value of the assigned variable.

[image]

You can write a general keyword as well that will take any keyword by name with its arguments, it will execute it and log the return value.

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def run_keyword_and_log_return_value(keyword, *args):
    BuiltIn().log(BuiltIn().run_keyword(keyword, *args))
```

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     var.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test 3
    Run Keyword And Log Return Value    Evaluate    1 + 2
    Run Keyword And Log Return Value    Set Variable    data
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bence, Your solution is overall perfect, but i was thinking of something in-built in robotframewark, so that i don't have to write extra lines or maintain extra python functions. Though not a show stopper for me, obviously work around always works. 

Thanks for the anwser.

Comment: @Zeeshan As per my knowledge of the framework this is what can be done, but maybe someone will correct me. :) You always have to store a return value in a variable before passing it on.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of logging the evaluate built in value, you can actually do [inline evaluate](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.2.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation) since robotframewrok 3.2

```
log    ${{ 1 + 2 }}
```

As mentioned, this is limited to evaluate and cannot be used for other defined keyword result